# Login popup with Identity framework in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin

I have an MVC 5 app that uses OWIN middleware for Identity Framework. Right now it's working correctly and sends unauthorized users to the Account/Login page. The app uses local login (not facebook/google etc).

I need to change it so that it opens a modal popup asking for username/password instead of redirecting to a page. How would I do that?

Update:
Thanks @SteveGreene and @chris. Let me clarify a little bit more. Yes I know I can easily use a modal popup when the user explicitly wants to login. What I want is when they click a link to a controller/action that requires authorization, instead of the app redirecting them to login page (or the controller page), it should show a popup. Once they login the page should then be redirected to the controller/action they requested. If I were to take Chris's suggestion and check within the controller, I would not be able to use [Authorize] attribute correct? Is there a better way then just checking for authentication manually in all the actions?

Comment: Heres one example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/993087/Use-Twitter-Bootstrap-Modal-Dialog-for-Smoother-Lo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, this is not any different than just a standard login form. The only real difference is that the form is within a modal popup hidden initially, part of the layout or otherwise on every page, and any login links you have will merely activate this popup rather than navigate to a new URL. After login, you're going to still want to do a redirect even if it's back to the same page, just so MVC can actually fill in the user principal in the HttpContext.

However, you're still going to need a standard login form for redirecting to when the user navigates to a page requiring authorization. First, you can't dynamically set the URL MVC will navigate unauthorized users to. It's set in the web.config and that's all you get. Second, even if you could, you can't simultaneously protect a page and display it, even if you intend to have a modal login form displayed on top of it. You would have to allow anonymous access to all pages, at which point you could determine if the user is authenticated or not on page and show the login form modal if necessary. However, at this point, a clever user could just dig into the developer tools of their browser and just remove the modal and proceed to work with the page.

Long and short, you can have a modal login form for when the user explicitly chooses to login, but if they hit a page requiring authorization, you'll still need a standard form to redirect them to.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question with a bit more requirements. Hoping to find a way to do this without duplicating code in all the controllers.

Comment: You don't have to duplicate any code. Just pass a return url in a hidden input with the form submission and redirect from your standard login post action. Like I said in my answer, though, what you're wanting (user gets a login popup when they attempt to go to a protected page) is not possible. The view would have to return in order to show the popup and it can't if it's protected. You could use `[AllowAnonymous]` to allow that, but then, like I said, you've effectively removed all protection as users can easily bypass your login modal.

Comment: Although not the answer I was hoping for, this seems to be the only way to do it so far. I implemented it this way. So marking this as accepted answer.

Comment: @Chris, Couldn't we just async call some action that would return if user is loged in or not and show popup or otherwize proceed with action?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: All content of the page would have to be dependent on that. In other words, you return a basically blank slate and then everything gets filled in based on your async request. If you return anything protected, you cannot count on JS alone to protect it.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, I think it will work for simple scenarios like, you are reading some news site and reading article. Now you click a button to add a comment. So you can async call the server action and return if user is logged in. Am I correct?